# What is the meaning of the double pipe in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have basic knowledge of Python and I'm trying to learn Ruby.  I see the following method has what appears to be a hash table.  I don't understand what the double pipe is doing and would appreciate it if someone could show me why this is used and the Python equivalent.

```
def request_raw(opts={})
        c_enc  = opts['encode']     || false
        c_uri  = opts['uri']        || '/'
        c_body = opts['data']       || ''
        c_meth = opts['method']     || 'GET'
        c_prot = opts['proto']      || 'HTTP'
```

For additional context, the method may be called as follows:

```
send request_raw({'uri' => '/', 'method' => 'GET'})
```

Comment: It's equivalent to python `or`, but not equivalent to Ruby `or` (it has a different precedence).

Comment: I just can't pick one from tons of similar question to close this one. [pick on yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ruby+double+pipe) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c_enc = opts['encode'] || false`

In this line if opts['encode'] is not nil, the value of c_enc will be set to opts['encode'] otherwise it will be false

Case 2

If the opts['encode'] is false, the false on the right side of `||` will be assigned to c_enc.

Other examples

```
    1  || false => 1 
    false || 1  => 1
    false || false => false
    true || false => true
    "foo" || false => "foo" #because string foo is not false or nil
    "foo1" || "foo2" => "foo1" #because foo1 is not false or nil, it short circuits and will not bother to evaluate the right hand side of ||
```

Basically in your example, opts['encode'] should not either false or nil. If it is other than false or nil, anything that is inside opts['encode'] will be assigned to c_enc

Now as per your question

you are passing a hash in the method call, opts is the receiving the argument. Now come to the first line

`c_enc  = opts['encode']  || false`, now `opts['encode'] = nil`, **opts is as hash. You lookup an entry in hash by hash['key']** So `c_env = false`

Comment: @EricDuminil is this a better version?

Comment: Better, yes. You could also show some examples with strings, not to give the impression that a boolean or a bit is needed.

Comment: Can you please also give an example using the call I gave in the original post?  Thanks

Comment: Did you understand @ade1e. If this helpful, consider accepting my answer. Thanks

Comment: I understand the nil concept thanks.  So why do we think the call example I provided has `'uri' => '/'` as an entry?  Is this so the call is implicit as my understanding now is that without this call the  `c_uri  = opts['uri']        || '/'` would give the same result if no value was passed in the call.  Please help me understand this then I will accept @gates.

Comment: So the statement is opts['uri'] || '/' will give '/' as output if nothing is passed, as opts['uri'] will become nil if it's not passed in the hash. Hope it helps!

Comment: It is passed in the hash @gates in the call.  Please see my original post example.  I now understand what happens if `nil` is passed but why do you think this call has 'uri' => '/' as would it not give the same result if no (nil) value was passed in the call?

Comment: Hey it's your code, how would I know what's your thought process behind this .. passing url value as '/' or nil does not make any difference.

Comment: It's not my code which is why I am asking these questions @gates.